# Por que usar const depois da função?

Tags: c++, classes, método

Notei em alguns códigos de outros programadores de C++ que usam funções como:

```
bool CClass::isRunning() const
{
    return this->_running;
}
```

Eu entendi que dessa maneira não é possível modificar nenhum membro da classe, apenas serve para retorno de valor. Então, por que usá-las? Existe algum benefício nisso? Não seria mais fácil e mais econômico chamar diretamente a variável do que criar uma função para isso?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Na verdade não se usa depois de uma função e sim depois de um método. Afinal o que ele faz é tornar o ponteiro para `this`, ou seja, para a instância atual, uma constante. Então você não pode alterar nenhum membro deste objeto. É uma forma de garantir que o método não produza efeitos colaterais no objeto.

Na verdade membros que sejam declarados como `mutable` podem ser alterados mesmo assim, então não é bem garantido.

Na medida do possível é útil fazer todos os métodos `const`. Isso facilita algumas otimizações e dá uma boa indicação para evitar que alguém altere o algoritmo de forma inapropriada e mexa no estado do objeto. Se um programador resolver criar mudança de estado no código ele terá que tirar o `const` para compilar. E isso é uma mudança na API da classe. Isso é uma proteção.

Vamos supor que essa classe tenha um método assim:

```
void CClass::Run() {
    this->_running = true;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Function/Const.cpp).

Não pode usar `const` porque o método está mudando o estado do objeto.

De fato pode ser melhor chamar direto a variável, se você tiver controle total sobre o código. Tem certeza que no futuro o acesso a essa variável não será só pegar o seu valor e terá um algoritmo que o manipule? Isso é feito preventivamente para depois não ter que alterar todos os códigos que vão consumir a sua classe. Feito com o método você cria uma [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101), o que flexibiliza o acesso.

Isso vale especialmente quando há *linkedição* dinâmica (DLL) onde você nem sabe como será chamado o código e uma indireção se faz necessária.

Comment: Ah sim. Entendi! Obrigado.